# How to secure only one page with SSL on Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

My web server hosts many pages. However, I need to secure only one of them with SSL. I know how to create self-signed certificate and how to install it on Apache2. My problem is quite different: since my web server hosts many pages and I need to secure only one of them, what exactly (and where and how) should I configure? Thanks!

Im using x86_64 GNU/Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: You can use a redirect rule to force a particular page for ssl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VirtualHost for your HTTP site, add

```
Redirect permanent /path/to/page https://example.com/path/to/page
```

See the docs for [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).  Note that this will leave the user on HTTPS as they continue browsing your site.